# MySQL - slight variation in limit has large variation in fetch time

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a medium sized data set of about 4m rows.

Running my query:

```
SELECT id
     , var1
     , var2 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE date< "2019-10-29" 
   and date>="2018-10-29" 
   and company_id = 17 
 LIMIT 260;
```

returns 253 rows and takes duration = 0.171 / fetch = 15.22s.

But when I vary the query to limit 240 rows:

```
SELECT id
     , var1
     , var2 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE date< "2019-10-29" 
   and date>="2018-10-29" 
   and company_id = 17 
 LIMIT 240;
```

It only takes 0.25s/0.000s.

**Why does the variation in limit drastically impact the fetch time?**

- An additional variation is if I restrict the date range to return less rows, this strangely ups the fetch time again (perhaps because the number or rows is less than the limit?)

Comment: Which is mysql's version? What happens if you place **SQL_NO_CACHE** after each select? `select sql_no_cache id, var1, ...`

Comment: sql_no_cache makes no difference, I think the mysql server version is 5.7.23

Comment: Anyways you should look at *duration time*, not at *fetch time*. I don't see any big difference between the two times.

Comment: practically I need the total time (duration+fetch) to be as small as possible

Comment: The *fetch time* does not depend on your query's performance. Please check this link for a clearer explanation: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425134/mysql-duration-and-fetch-time)

Comment: and yet the structure of the query **is** clearly impacting the total time of the query

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: adding `order by date desc` changes the time to 16.00s/0.00s, so it flips the duration and fetch. Does the order by statement occur after the where clause (i.e. orders the 253 rows)?

Comment: assuming you have index both columns correctly, I guess it might be related to index size. when you are reading 240 records you are reading less index pages. lets say the 241th record is created about a year ago and there are 1 million records created after that, your database server need to navigate more index pages to find those extra records which in turn gives you more fetch time.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it by adding an index to the table:

```
create index var1_index on table1(var1);
```